# Get only rows with the last consecutive year

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I have a basic table that looks like this:

[image: Original Table]

My goal is to get for each course_name and year the DIFFERENCE between it's rate and the rate of the same course_name with the last consecutive year BEFORE it.

So for example for:

```
course_name = hedva1
year = 2016
```

I'm hoping to get:

```
course_name = hedva1
year = 2016
rate = 9.50000 - 4.0000 = 5.50000
```

And for:

```
course_name = hedva1
year = 2015
```

I'm hoping to get:

```
course_name = hedva1
year = 2015
rate = 4.0000 - 2.0000 = 2.0000
```

My first logical step was to cross the table with itself which gets me this:

[image: Crossed Table]

And now I'm trying to get that specific result with different "WHERE"'s but can't figure it out.

For the rows that DON'T have any consecutive years before just show nothing it's fine.

Answer (score 0):

One method for getting the previous value is a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*,
       (select t2.rate_avg
        from t t2
        where t2.course = t.course and t2.year < t.year
        order by t2.year desc
        limit 1
       ) as prev_rate_avg
from t;
```

The rest of the answer is just arithmetic.

Comment: That's cool thanks, I'll clarify:

I don't know that I'll be getting consecutive years like 2016 and 2015. I might get values like 2016 and 2012 and then I need the DIFFERENCE between 2016 and the last time the course was in the table so it will be:
2016[rate] - 2012[rate]

Makes sense?
Thanks

Comment: @yoni . . . That is what this query does.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to cross join, because you know already something about the candidate records to join: same course_name, smaller year. So inner join, order by the older years found, limit your result to one row.

```
select
  ynow.course_name,
  ynow.year,
  ynow.rate_avg,
  yold.year,
  yold.rate_avg,
  ynow.rate_avg - yold.rate_avg as rate
from mytable ynow
join mytable yold where yold.course_name = ynow.course_name and yold.year < ynow.year
where ynow.course_name = 'hedva1'
  and ynow.year = 2016
order by yold.year desc
limit 1;
```